# What typeset -i2 var=2#0 means in bash/korn shell?

Tags: sh, ksh

I read the following instruction in a korn shell script:

```
typeset -i2 var=2#0
```

I managed to know that with `typeset` you can specify the type of variables and that the parameter `-i2` describes that the variable is an integer to be interpreted in radix 2 (binary).
However, I still can't understand what the value assigned to the variable (`2#0`) means.

Googling I found that instruction like `variable#pattern` mean that occurrences of the pattern will be deleted from the front of the variable, but this don't seem to be the case...

EDIT: Seems that the `-in` syntax is specific to korn shell (`ksh`)

Comment: In ksh `sh (AT&T Research) 93u+ 2012-08-01` this `echo "$var"` shows simply `2#0` so maybe that's simply the value of this variable without any special meaning?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk: No that initializing `var` as binary `0`. One could initialize 15 this way in binary as `2#1111`

Comment: This is not really a [tag:bash] question: `bash: typeset: -2: invalid option`, although bash does incorporate the "base#value" syntax in arithmetic context (which `typeset/declare/local -i` introduces: `declare -i x=16#deadbeef; echo $x`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-i[n]` syntax of `typeset` is specific to `ksh` and not available in `bash`. In your attempt the code `-i2` means represent the output in a base 2 content, i.e. as a binary value. On `ksh93`

```
typeset -i2 var=15
echo "$var"
```

produces the value in binary

```
2#1111
```

So with that logic, your original code initializes a value for `var` in binary `0`. Had you initialized with something as `2#1111`, it would have made more sense to what the flag meant. You cannot use non base 2 numbers with this syntax as it would simply throw a syntax error i.e. something like doing `typeset -i2 var=2#15` would never work.

Note that `typeset` is an outdated construct in both `ksh` and `bash` shells. Using `declare` provides similar options and more. In `bash` you could use the arithmetic operator for the same `$((..))`, if you define a number in base 2

```
var='2#1111'
echo "$(( var ))"
15
```

But there is no built-in way to do the base 2 conversion from decimal in `bash` without using a third party tool like `bc`

```
echo 'obase=2;15' | bc
1111
```

Comment: Another way with dc : echo '15 2op' | dc